# Split and join strings in a column using R

Tags: r, matrix, split

```
row.names X33 X40 X46 X50 X60 X80 X90 X100 X130 X200
INTERGENIC-chrI-188881-G-C  0.37    0.41    0.48    0.45    0.47    0.42    0.45    0.44    0.40    0.36    0.36    0.33    0.39
INTERGENIC-chrI-188939-A-G  0.38    0.48    0.56    0.54    0.57    0.45    0.57    0.51    0.49    0.47    0.41    0.38    0.52
INTERGENIC-chrXIII-191990-A-T   0.14    0.15    0.15    0.22    0.16    0.16    0.15    0.31    0.11    0.23    0.12    0.12    0.19
SDS3-chrIX-202625-T-G   0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.33    0.35    0.41    0.50    0.53
INTERGENIC-chrVIII-236987-G-A   0.15    0.34    0.28    0.28    0.22    0.12    0.15    0.25    0.27    0.24    0.13    0.13    0.25
INTERGENIC-chrVIII-236993-T-A   0.12    0.25    0.21    0.19    0.17    0.00    0.00    0.18    0.16    0.17    0.08    0.11    0.12
```

I have a matrix [34,11] with column names:

```
row.names X33 X40 X46 X50 X60 X80 X90 X100 X130 X200
```

The first column`row.names` needs to be split into individual columns:

```
GENE, CHROMOSOME, POSITION, REF, ALT (INTERGENIC-chrI-188881-G-C)
```

I am currently using R to get the desired output.

```
library(reshape2)    
A <- colsplit(df$row.names, "\\-", names=c("GENE", "CHROMOSOME", "POSITION", "REF", "ALT"))
```

I would like to perform this operation for all individual rows in the matrix. Could any one help me output a matrix as above with the new columns added. Thanks

Comment: Did you try `strsplit`?

Comment: Yes I did. But it splits just the header for me. I am a complete newbie. How can I use it on the matrix as a whole. Would you be able to give me a command. thanks

Comment: The form of your data is not exactly clear. Can you update your question with a few more lines and in a form that is easy for others to reproduce.

Comment: I would recommend using [my `cSplit` function](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733/) for this.

Comment: @AnandaMahto looks like genotype data, rows are `VariantID`, columns are `SampleIDs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#dummy data
df <- read.table(text="
Variants    33  40  46  50  60  80  90  100 130 200
ASG1-chrIX-103160-C-T   0   0   0   0   0   0.83    0.49    0   0   0
YNL179C-chrXIV-300948-T-A   0.27    0.32    0.24    0.25    0.23    0.22    0.17    0.16    0.2 0.3
",header=TRUE)

#split columns
temp_df <- 
  do.call(rbind,
          strsplit(as.character(df$Variants),split="-"))
colnames(temp_df) <- c("GENE", "CHROMOSOME", "POSITION", "REF", "ALT")

#result
cbind(temp_df,df[,-1])

# GENE CHROMOSOME POSITION REF ALT  X33  X40  X46  X50  X60  X80  X90 X100 X130 X200
# 1    ASG1      chrIX   103160   C   T 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.83 0.49 0.00  0.0  0.0
# 2 YNL179C     chrXIV   300948   T   A 0.27 0.32 0.24 0.25 0.23 0.22 0.17 0.16  0.2  0.3
```

**EDIT:**

The code your provided works, too:

```
#using reshape2
library(reshape2)
A <- colsplit(df$Variants, "\\-", names=c("GENE", "CHROMOSOME", "POSITION", "REF", "ALT"))

#result
cbind(A,df[,-1])
```

Comment: Above code works on sample data you provided. How does your `temp_df` look like?

Comment: Am I doing it right? df <- read.table(dataFiltered8, header=TRUE, sep = "-"). So it the exact format as I mentioned in my question with 34 rows.

Comment: The solution you provided using `colsplit` works, just needed to `cbind` to original `df`.

Comment: using colsplit and cbind I get an error  Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 34

Comment: It is hard to tell where it is failing, it would help if you could provide more rows from your file?

Comment: I have updated the query with more rows. Does this help?

Comment: You need to provide enough rows, so the suggested solution would fail... Then we can explore further. So far above solution works for additional rows, too.

Comment: Here is how the original data looks like.Would this help? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi zx8754, I kind of figured out in which step there is an error. The command outputs an empty temp_df. Could you help me sort this please?

Comment: Sorry to be repetitive but we need to know more about your input data, post anonymised full version on dropbox to share?

Comment: Hi zx8754, here is the link to the file test.csv  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/06plzka94b2huef/AAAz6SwIqKZLtJB8hAZuJ1qNa  Hope this helps.

Comment: Again... for me above code works for dropbox file. Does it fail for you?